# How can I build this header?

Tags: magento2, header, design

I'm trying to get the header to look a little like this: 
[image]

I'm having a hard time with the search and mini cart buttons, it seems they're nested within header-wrapper by default and I can't seem to separate them from that container and move them around individually.

This is where I'm up to:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/headercontact.phtml" name="headercontact"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/headercolumn1.phtml" name="headercolumn1"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/headercolumn2.phtml" name="headercolumn2"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/headercolumn3.phtml" name="headercolumn3"/>
          </container>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

So - I created 3 columns inside the header-wrapper container, and then moved the top search and mini cart with CSS. 
Ideally I would be able to get them both into columns 1 and 3 so that I can put them in DIVS and style them but adding this to headercolumn1.phtml doesn't seem to work

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch'); ?>
```

so they're both currently sitting below the columns from the header-wrapper container.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') would only work in the headercolumn1.phtml if you had a block called "topSearch" nested inside of the headercolumn1 block. You could maybe move topSearch inside of it, or make a new block within headercolumn1 in the XML with topSearch's class and template, but different name, and then use that new block name in the getChildHtml method.

Perhaps like:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/headercolumn1.phtml" name="headercolumn1">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="newSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
</block>
```

and then $this->getChildHtml('newSearch') in the template?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! How would I go about doing both of those? Where do I find topSearch's template or how would I nest topSearch into the column block?

Comment: Hey @iwfabric, no prob -- check my updated answer for the suggested XML

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

I tried doing the same for minicart in headercolumn3 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="newMiniCart" template="Magento_Checkout::minicart.phtml" />
But it dosn't work? Do I have the wrong template? Developer mode dosn't work for me so I'm having to do a lot of guess work with template paths..

Comment: Maybe for that one it'd be better to move the _existing_ block inside the headercolumn3 block (<move element="minicart" destination="headercolumn3"/> and then use getChildHtml('minicart') in headercolumn3.phtml